# Capturing command-line output using Java

Tags: java, process, outputstream

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/chess/h.exe");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("uci");
while (true) System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

It writes:

```
 Houdini 4 Pro x64 (c) 2013 Robert Houdart

 info string 4 processor(s) found info string NUMA configuration with 1
 node(s), offset 0 info string 128 MB Hash
```

If I doing the same in console, the result is [image]

Where did other text dissapeared? How can I make it been seen using my program?

Comment: The problem is in writing to the process. Here's [solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903549/writing-to-inputstream-of-a-java-process

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the error output as well, it might be the case that the h.exe program only prints "info" messages to the standard output and everything else is sent to the error output.

```
process.getErrorStream();
```