# How to "pick up" all console output from a specific Java application?

Tags: java, console, windows-console

I'm creating a simple Java application to pick up all console output from a specific Java application, but I cant figure out how to pick up all the data.

I'm going to use it for Minecraft Forge servers, to create a custom GUI for the server, and because batch-files which starts the server presents the data in the console, I guess the application uses the default `System.out` stream for writing to the console.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing stdout when calling Runtime.exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec)

Comment: If you don't want to start the minecraft server from your application, a simple option would be to redirect the server's output to a file and read that.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard There is no problems starting it from my application, I think, but how do I redirect the output from the server to a file?

Comment: Do that when starting the server, for example on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Is there a way to also send input back to the server application, so that I can excecute commands on the server, like /stop, /op etc.?

Comment: If you start it from your application (see my first comment), yes, otherwise I'm not sure.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Okay, I'll try to start it from my application. How do I execute commands then?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903549/writing-to-inputstream-of-a-java-process